# Recursive function return issue

Tags: php, recursion

I'm writing a recursive function like below:

```
 private function getManager($employee)
 {
     $manager = $employee->manager;
     if ($manager) {
         array_push($this->managers, $manager->id);
         $this->getManager($manager);
     }
     return;
 }
```

This function receive an employee and find his manage. If find a manage, then push **manager id** into an array (**$this->managers** on line 5). Then call this function recursively and pass manager as an employee. If no manager found on line 3, then this function just return (line 8).

So my question is, is their any problem if i'm not return the recursive call at line 6 (**$this->getManager($manager);**)

Comment: Please post an example `$employee` structure here (ideally with [var_export()](https://www.php.net/var_export) output).

Comment: Are you missing the `$` in `employee->manager`?

Comment: This is work properly, but my question is, is there any need to use return at line 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you think, but it works.

```php
function getManagers($employee)
{
  $managers = [];
  if (isset($employee->manager)) {
    array_push($managers, $employee->manager->id);
    array_push($managers, ...getManagers($employee->manager));
  }
  return $managers;
}
```

Comment: my code work properly, but my question is, is there any need to use return at line 6 ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to return?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is absolutely no benefit in writing the empty return.  The method will halt regardless of the existence of the `return`.

Please observe the two methods below which show identical, error-less outcomes regardless of the return.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gth16))

```
class Management
{
    private $managers = [];

    function __construct($managerTree)
    {
        $this->getManager($managerTree);
        var_export($this->managers);

        echo "\n---\n";
        $this->managers = [];
        var_export($this->managers);

        echo "\n---\n";
        $this->getManager2($managerTree);
        var_export($this->managers);
    }

    private function getManager(?object $employee): void
    {
        $manager = $employee->manager;
        if ($manager) {
            array_push($this->managers, $manager->id);
            $this->getManager($manager);
        }
        return;
    }

    private function getManager2(?object $employee): void
    {
        $manager = $employee->manager;
        if ($manager) {
            array_push($this->managers, $manager->id);
            $this->getManager($manager);
        }
    }
}

new Management(
    (object) [
        'id' => 3,
        'manager' => (object) [
            'id' => 2,
            'manager' => (object) [
                'id' => 1,
                'manager' => null
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 2,
  1 => 1,
)
---
array (
)
---
array (
  0 => 2,
  1 => 1,
)
```